# How to concatenate xsl:value-of with separator

Tags: xslt, concatenation, separator, value-of

Given XML:

```
<issueDate day="30" month="09" year="2015"/>
```

I wanted to build a string that output: 2015-09-30

This worked:

```
<xsl:variable name="issueDate" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(//issueDate/@year,'-',//issueDate/@month,'-',//issueDate/@day)" />
</xsl:variable>
```

...

```
<xsl:value-of select="$issueDate"/>
```

But this threw an error (expected EOF, found ','):

```
<xsl:value-of select="//issueDate/@year,//issueDate/@month,//issueDate/@day" separator="-" />
```

What is the syntax to select more than one value using separator attribute?

Comment: Are you sure you are using an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9, XmlPrime or AltovaXML? The `separator` attribute of `xsl:value-of` and the sequence operator `,` are part of XSLT/XPath 2.0 and are not supported with XSLT 1.0 processors.

Comment: I'm using Antenna House, it's possible it's 1.0, thank you.

Comment: If you have a version that works, why are you wasting your time asking question about an alternative that does not work?

Comment: I wanted to know how to select more than one attribute at a time without using concat. I apologize for wasting anyone's time, I don't consider it a waste of my time because I learned something.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use XPath-2.0/XSLT-2.0, you could use [`string-join`](https://www.data2type.de/en/xml-xslt-xslfo/xslt/xslt-xpath-function-reference/alphabetical-xslt-and-xpath-reference/string-join/):

```
<xsl:for-each select="//issueDate">
  <xsl:value-of select="string-join( (@year, @month, @day), '-')" />
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>   <!-- just for pretty output -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thank you zx485, I got the same error and I just discovered I am using XSL 1.1.